# SALESFORCE : Email template conditional field not working

Tags: if-statement, templates, salesforce

I am currently working on an email template, and I can't seem to be able to reference a field in a IF statement.

The current line I'm having trouble with:

```
{!IF(Demande_CPT__c.Reponse_Partenaire__c ="Place disponible",”{!Demande_CPT__c.Date_expiration_option__c}”,"notfrench")}
```

We tried :

```
{!IF("{!Demande_CPT__c.Reponse_Partenaire__c}" !="Place disponible",”{!Demande_CPT__c.Date_expiration_option__c}”,"notfrench")}

{!IF("{!Demande_CPT__c.Reponse_Partenaire__c}" !="Place disponible",Demande_CPT__c.Date_expiration_option__c,"notfrench")}
```

but nothing seems to work...

The field evaluates to true and we can get a string to show up but not the field reference. I hope I make sense.
If you have any idea !

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You already are in the "merge field syntax" of `{!text has special meaning here}`, you don't need another `{!` inside it. And your quote signs are wrong, they need to be plain `""`, not fancy `„“`. If you edited the template in MS Word it likely injected some rubbish in it with hidden `<span></span>` tags that also can completely mess the field merging up.

Try with `{!IF(Demande_CPT__c.Reponse_Partenaire__c = "Place disponible",Demande_CPT__c.Date_expiration_option__c,"notfrench")}`

What is it, normal template or Visualforce? From what I remember normal templates are limited and for IFs you might have to waste a formula field... But Visualforce should work OK

Some more help: https://trailblazers.salesforce.com/answers?id=90630000000gpkYAAQ

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer! I actually already noticed the weird quote things and I tested with correct ones and it didn’t work either. And then we tried to reference a standard field and it worked like a charm... We’re using the normal email template, so yeah I think that’s what the issue is.